# How do I underline some text in a label using ZK framework?

Tags: zk

I am using ZK framework.  I have a static line of text in a label:

```
        <label
            value="If you have already submitted a leave application or need to modify 
                   an existing leave, do not submit an online application.  " />
```

I need to underline only some parts of this sentence.  I've tried putting `<u> </u>` around the text I wish to underline, but this is not allowed in ZK.

I've also tried creating separate labels, with `style="text-decoration: underline;"` which does underline the specified text.  However this way of underlining makes each label display on it's own line.

Is there some way that I can underline only certain parts of my label?

Comment: Put multiple labels next to each other with certain ones underlined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you could append style to certain parts of a label.

Like @Link already commented you could use multiple labels and set the sclass different of each label.

If you have real HTML in your text, you could use the following :

```
HtmlNativeComponent n = new HtmlNativeComponent("html", "<h2>title</h2>","<p>your text</p>");
```

Explication of constructor :

- `"html"` => the element where all your text is between. (wrapper element)
- `"<h2>title</h2>"` => the first part. If you append more children to the native component, its **after** this they will come.
- `"<p>your text</p>"` => the second part. If you append more children to the native component, its **before** this they will come.